# Rectifier for bike dynamo

Tags: mosfet, rectifier

I'm building a lighting system for a bike, powered by a dynamo (typically rated 6V, 3W max). The load will include LEDs and a bit of logic (such as N555/ATTiny85 for blinking, etc.). I also plan to include some form of short-term energy storage (for red lights): either a supercapacitor or a small lithium battery.

What is an appropriate choice for rectifying the 6V AC input? Obvious choices are:

- a full-wave diode bridge rectifier (pro: easy and cheap, exists as a single-package; con: but at a low voltage, that 1.5V loss stings a bit);
- a Schottky diode bridge (a bit more efficient, a bit pricier, I don't believe it exists as a single package);
- a simple [MOSFET bridge](http://www.thetaeng.com/designIdeas/FETBridge.html), which I used in a previous iteration of this circuit, but it apparently cannot charge a capacitor (although I believe I used it successfully for that purpose in said previous circuit...), which can have a low drop but is more cumbersome;
- a MOSFET bridge driven by a [LT4320](https://www.powerelectronics.com/technologies/pmics/article/21860447/lt4320-ideal-diode-bridge-controller-cuts-power-dissipation-improves-efficiency): I've never used this component, and it apparently needs at least 9V to work. Also, I've never soldered SMD yet.
- there seems to be a dedicated chip, [FDMQ8203](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TND6234-D.PDF), but that is a bit expensive (incl. shipping cost) for a chip I'm not sure to be able to solder (tiny MLP package).

Did I miss any other rectifier circuits, and is my evaluation of the pros and cons of each type of rectifier accurate?

Comment: Technically bikes use alternators. Dynamos generate DC. Dynamo is the common (mis-)terminology however.

Comment: Is it for _a_ bike or for bikes? If it's for a product in series production I wouldn't worry too much about soldering.

Comment: It's for one-ish bike - mine, and then *maybe* those of my immediate family. Definitely not a series production. (Although the complete circuit, STL, etc. might end up on Instructables or the like one day, this will be somebody else's problem).

Answer (score 1):

If your LEDs are not in series then about 3.5 VDC  will suffice for short term battery operation and maybe 4v+  when directly powered.

A Schottky diode bridge will drop about 1 volt, allowing reasonable headroom from a 6 V alternator.. 6VAC will rectify to around 7V+ under load.

A single lithium ion cell will be suitable for this application. A readily available TP4056; charger module with under voltage discharge protection should do what is needed.
A fully charged battery, + Schottky diode will provide about 3.5VDC  to the LED circuitry. When the alternator is operating the voltage will exceed the battery voltage and the battery will not discharge.

Answer (score 1):

A MOSFET bridge as shown won't charge a capacitor since it also allows current to flow in reverse. You can add a Schottky diode at the output, or just replace the bottom 2 MOSFETs with two schottkys.

A bike 'dynamo' acts like a constant current source -- so when lighting a lamp, the brightness doesn't change much with speed. It does this because while the voltage generated rises with speed, so does the impedance (Z) from the inductance of the winding -- the net result is that the V/Z remains quite constant. So, if your LEDs don't fully load the dynamo, its voltage (and so the rectifier voltage) will become quite high -- you will need a high BV rectifier, and if you use MOSFETs, be sure their VGS isn't exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

The question has arisen before on this site and I can't find an answer that tackles your exact question. In the meantime you may find some of the following questions and answers of interest.

- [Calculating max power of bicycle dynamo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325991/calculating-max-power-of-bicycle-dynamo/325998#325998)
- [In a shimano dynamo hub with 6V regulator rest of power is being wasted?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498144/in-a-shimano-dynamo-hub-with-6v-regulator-rest-of-power-is-being-wasted)
- [Converting and Stabilizing output voltage of a dynamo hub](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57039/converting-and-stabilizing-output-voltage-of-a-dynamo-hub)
- [Charge battery with AC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/314502/charge-battery-with-ac)